unable to get icmp blackbox to work icmp allowed for my user
I am trying to get started with a simple ping to several devices in my network, i am just running everything natively on a ubuntu vm, i can ping my devices in my terminal fine, but i am unable to get blackbox_exporter icmp to work
the following is returned
ts=2024-07-05T11:50:47.265726008Z caller=handler.go:120 module=icmp target=192.168.18.81 level=debug msg="Unable to do unprivileged listen on socket, will attempt privileged" err="socket: permission denied"
ts=2024-07-05T11:50:47.265756288Z caller=handler.go:120 module=icmp target=192.168.18.81 level=error msg="Error listening to socket" err="listen ip4:icmp 0.0.0.0: socket: operation not permitted"

I already created a file 99-allow-ping.conf under /etc/sysctl.d
which contains the following
net.ipv4.ping_group_range=1000 10001

what am i missing?
my blackbox.yml content
modules:
  http_2xx:
    prober: http
    http:
      preferred_ip_protocol: "ip4"
  http_post_2xx:
    prober: http
    http:
      method: POST
  tcp_connect:
    prober: tcp
  pop3s_banner:
    prober: tcp
    tcp:
      query_response:
      - expect: "^+OK"
      tls: true
      tls_config:
        insecure_skip_verify: false
  grpc:
    prober: grpc
    grpc:
      tls: true
      preferred_ip_protocol: "ip4"
  grpc_plain:
    prober: grpc
    grpc:
      tls: false
      service: "service1"
  ssh_banner:
    prober: tcp
    tcp:
      query_response:
      - expect: "^SSH-2.0-"
      - send: "SSH-2.0-blackbox-ssh-check"
  irc_banner:
    prober: tcp
    tcp:
      query_response:
      - send: "NICK prober"
      - send: "USER prober prober prober :prober"
      - expect: "PING :([^ ]+)"
        send: "PONG ${1}"
      - expect: "^:[^ ]+ 001"
  icmp:
    prober: icmp
  icmp_ttl5:
    prober: icmp
    timeout: 5s
    icmp:
      ttl: 5

prometheus.yml
ts=2024-07-05T11:50:47.265726008Z caller=handler.go:120 module=icmp target=192.168.18.81 level=debug msg="Unable to do unprivileged listen on socket, will attempt privileged" err="socket: permission denied"
ts=2024-07-05T11:50:47.265756288Z caller=handler.go:120 module=icmp target=192.168.18.81 level=error msg="Error listening to socket" err="listen ip4:icmp 0.0.0.0: socket: operation not permitted"


it was indeed the net.ipv4.ping_group_range=1000 10001 group id that was insufficient
